# Conversion of com.google.cloud.datastore.Key object to com.google.datastore.v1.Key object using Java Google cloud datastore APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Has any one tried to convert the com.google.cloud.datastore.Key object to com.google.datastore.v1.Key object using Java APIs. The problem is I have a query executed with the com.google.cloud.datastore.* APIs  but the Dataflow’s DataStoreIO API only allows the v1 Objects to go through.

```
 Query<com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity> query =
 Query.newEntityQueryBuilder().setNamespace(options.getNameSpace())
                                 .setKind(options.getKind())                      .setFilter(StructuredQuery.PropertyFilter.hasAncestor(key))
                                 .build();
 Transaction transaction = datastore.newTransaction();
 QueryResults<com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity> results = transaction.run(query);
 com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity[] keys = Iterators.toArray(results, com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity.class);
  if(keys.length > 0){
 int i = keys.length - 1;
 while(i > 0){
 String keyStream = keys[i].getKey().toString();
 LOG.info("keyStream::::",keyStream);
 com.google.datastore.v1.Key keyV1 = com.google.datastore.v1.Key.parseFrom(keys[i].getKey().toString().getBytes());
 i--;
  }
 }
```

Every time I am getting Invalid Protocol missing wire type exception in this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `toPb()` method on the [com.google.cloud.datastore.Key](https://github.com/googleapis/java-datastore/blob/main/google-cloud-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/datastore/BaseKey.java#L184) object

Comment: this method is default method. not in public method. can't be used ouside of the package.

'toPb()' is not public in 'com.google.cloud.datastore.BaseKey'. Cannot be accessed from outside package